# Cell format for screen headers

Tags: notebooks, formatting

If one picks the menu option Format->Edit Stylesheet and then one opens the "Default.nb" link, the newly opened notebook has a header that reads "Deafult.nb" style definitions. In one navigates down in the page, that header stays in place. However, none of the header styles defined in Default.nb produce that specific header.

What is the style to produce that type of static header? What are the menu commands (if any) to dock cells?

Comment: It is a `DockedCell`.

Comment: @rm-rf: I selected the cell, pressed `Ctrl+Shit+E`, changed the cell style to `DockedCell`, pressed `Ctrl+Shift+E` again. The cell did change the style but it does not stay docked. On second thought, there must be more to it that changing the style. Somehow, it must be specified to the notebook (`Options` maybe). I have edited the question.

Comment: It's not a style (well, kind of), but an option to the notebook. The docs for `DockedCells` has a simplified example and there are some more examples [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=dockedcells%20).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you find a notebook with a docked cell evaluate

```
Options[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells]
```

to see what has been added to the docked cell option. Please read the docs and the link @rm -rf provided but a quick way to add a docked cell:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 DockedCells -> {ToBoxes@
    Pane["Final Episode of Breaking Bad. Check your local guides", 
     BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "arial", 16]]}]
```